# how to decrypt password in mvc using Crypto.HashPassword()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i am using  Crypto.HashPassword() method for generate password.can you help me to decrypt that hasspassword which i created hashed  password using Crypto.HashPassword() method

Comment: If that was easily possible then using hashed passwords wouldn't be useful at all.

Comment: Are you trying to compare the entered password to the stored password? If so, you should encrypt the input as well, and compare the encrypted strings.

Comment: No,i am trying to decrypting that password

Comment: Then it depends on the algorithm used, but if it's any half-decent one then you probably have to brute force it to get a hash conflict.

Comment: that process does not able to decrypting Crypto.HashPassword() method's hashed password

Comment: hi  Dirk what ever it's useful or not could you please give me example code how to do?

Comment: Martin Liversage u had put this question has duplicate but still i didnt find the excat solution could please give the solution or idea for this